# Draftjs v0.10 - how to create Entities during deserialisation

Tags: entity, deserialization, draftjs

I am using a custom serialiser/deserialiser for draftjs, which creates a ContentState bottom-up, building a character metadata list with attached styles and Entities, creating the ContentBlock from that, and finally creates the ContentState using createFromBlockArray.

In v0.10, the Entity.create will be removed, and a ContentState instance will be required to create entities. How to create Entities when I don't yet have a ContentState instance?